# How to delete item with icon from adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

I am trying to delete from adapter an icon with item(text) from adapter.
I know it looks like a simple task and I did it but still have some bug on it. Its looks like the item that I delete them get strange that first icon in the list and the last one get the same icon.
Here's the code:

```
ListRssLinkAndTitle=(ArrayList)dbAdpter.getWantedItemsList(this,"RssTitle","link","Rtl","image");//get wanted items from db 

        for (int j=0;j<ListRssLinkAndTitle.size();j++)
            listKeys.add(ListRssLinkAndTitle.get(j).title);

        for (int i=0;i<ListRssLinkAndTitle.size();i++)
            Icon.add(ListRssLinkAndTitle.get(i).icon);

        listAdapter = new ListRssAdpter(this, R.layout.titlesrss, listKeys,Icon);

            lv.setAdapter(listAdapter); 
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
            {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                        if  (0<dbAdpter.deleteRssItem(ListRssLinkAndTitle.get(position).title,ListRssLinkAndTitle.get(position).url))
                        {
                            ListRssLinkAndTitle.remove(position);
                            listAdapter.items.remove(position);
                            listAdapter.FavIconList.remove(position);


                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  getResources().getString(R.string.operationFaild),0).show();
                }
            } 

        });
```

and the adapter:

```
public class ListRssAdpter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private int id;
    public List<String> items;
    public List<byte[]> FavIconList;
    public boolean iconRemove=false;
    public int IconHigh=-1;// if -1 not in use

    //constractor for fav icon
    public ListRssAdpter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> list,List<byte[]> icon) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        mContext = context;
        id = textViewResourceId;
        items = list;
        this.FavIconList=icon;
    }

public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        View mView = v;
        if (mView==null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mView = vi.inflate(id, null);

        }
        ImageView   removeIcon = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.iconremove); 
        ImageView   favIcon = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.iconfav); 
        if (iconRemove)
        {
            removeIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            favIcon.setVisibility(favIcon.GONE);
        }
        else 
        {
            if (FavIconList.get(position)!=null)
            {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(FavIconList.get(position), 0, FavIconList.get(position).length);
            favIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mView.getContext().getResources(),R.drawable.rss);
            removeIcon.setVisibility(removeIcon.GONE);
            favIcon.setVisibility(favIcon.VISIBLE);
        }


        TextView tx = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textView);


        //if this view is on main screen
        if (tx == null) {
            tx = ((TextView) mView);
        }
        if (this.IconHigh!=-1)
            tx.setHeight(this.IconHigh);
        //this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);

        tx.setText(items.get(position));
        return mView;

    }
}
```

If you can't find a logic error  maybe you can give me a simple example working code :)

Comment: Its not necessairy to remove the items from the adapter, you can remove directly from listKeys and call notifydatasetchanged. You can use the viewHolder pattern to reuse view objects in your view method. I don't know the exact solution but search for some examples regarding adapters. there is enough sample code on the web regarding this topic

Comment: Also, it's not good practice to be able to access the internal fields of the Adapter like you did there, don't make them public.

Comment: Do you simply want to add (or remove) a "favorite" icon when the user clicks a row?

Comment: @Sam yes I want to delete the item with fav icon